# Left css value on Jquery Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have made a simple keylistening code, the point is to move the div to the left when I press the left arrow and obviously to the right when the right arrow is pressed. I want to assign the Left css value of the #divcar to a variable. This is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Car game</title>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            #divcar {
                position: absolute;
                top: 60%;
                left: 49%;
                height: 70px;
                width: auto;
            }
            #car {
                height: 70px;
                width: auto;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var left = $('#divcar').left();
                $(document).keydown(function(e) {
                    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
                        alert("left pressed");
                        $("#divcar").css('left', left - '10%');
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
                        alert("right pressed");
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="divcar">
            <img src="car_topview.png" alt="Car" height="70" id="car" />
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

The problem is that when I run the code, I get this error: TypeError: $(...).left is not a function.

How do I fix this

Thanks

Comment: Replace `.left()` with a function that actually exists ... for example `.css('left')`.

Comment: Oh, and that `-10%` is not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
var left = $('#divcar').left();
```

"Left" is not a jquery function. You need to use:

```
var left = $('#divcar').css('left');
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that `$('#divcar').left()` is not a function (as said)..

And `$("#divcar").css('left', left - '10%');` won't work as `left - 10%` is not a proper number.

Your code should be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var left = $('#divcar').css('left') * 1, // use *1 to be sure that left is a number
        offset = 0.1 * left; // get the 10% i.e. 10/100 = 0.1
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
            alert( "left pressed" );
            $("#divcar").css('left', left - offset);
            return false;
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 39) {
            alert( "right pressed" );
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

You also could simplify it by getting directly 90% (i.e. 0.9) of `left`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var newleft = $('#divcar').css('left') * 0.9;
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
            alert( "left pressed" );
            $("#divcar").css('left', newleft);
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 39) {
            alert( "right pressed" );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me with the var, but the snippet you made dont work. When I press left, it does not move.

Comment: Can you make a simple jsfiddle please?